# Preventing user drag in bottomsheet when recyclerview inside bottomsheet android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I have relativelayout as bottomsheet behaviour. inside relativelayout, I have imageview and below it recyclerview. Now I want to prevent dragging when user swipe down in recyclerview. I have tried setting mode expanded in onStateChanged method, but it seems not working as I have recyclerview.

```
mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomsheetLayout);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

           if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }

    });
```

my xml file is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:id="@+id/dragView1">




    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/iv_close"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_5"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
        android:id="@+id/ivItemsClose"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="32dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rcBoutique"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</Relativelayout>
```

How to prevent dragging so that bottomsheet does not collapse?

Comment: Any luck? I've run into the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I also facing this issue then I resolved it by using `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` in RecyclerView, this line can disable nested scrolling behaviour.

BottomSheet and Recyclerview both has scolling behaviour that's why this issue is generated.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rcBoutique"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
```

Comment: This was the missing link for me. Using this in conjunction with Mihir's answer worked for me and I was still able to scroll my recycler view without dragging the bottom sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue using a ListView and BottomSheetDialog. I believe it's the same unwanted result. Attempting to scroll the list could dismiss the bottom sheet.

My fix was to use `bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false);` to prevent the bottomSheet from reacting to the scroll action. The scroll gesture now only manipulates the ListView. I have an 'ok' and 'cancel' button for those actions.